# Cheap material and construction to insulate balcony during the winter?

Tags: materials, architecture, thermal-insulation

It's a long shot, but I was wondering whether there is any material I can wrap around my balcony to be able to use it like a sun room during the winter. A plastic-like material that I could span around my balcony and somehow seal to the outside of my balcony door, thereby allowing me to keep the balcony door open. It would need to be cheap and fairly easily removable.

Comment: Perhaps PVC film. Google “temporary greenhouse” for ideas.

Comment: Also, you can check all materials on makeitfrom(.)com

Comment: 2 layers of plastic with an 1-2in air gap should be pretty effective.

Comment: It will be very easy for the wind to remove it for you :) You might consider moving this question to the DIY forum to gain more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need heavy-gauge flexible vinyl "curtains" which are sold to close off breezeways, patios, balconies and store entrances/exits so conditioned air is not lost to the environment. This material is also used to make side curtains for boat canopies and sometimes convertible tops on sports cars.